# formula of square of the covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I am stuck with the calculation of $(\nabla ^2 \beta)(X,Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r)$.

In the following, capital letters are arbitrary vector fields.

Suppose $\beta$ is an $(r,0)$ tensor. Denote $(\nabla \beta)(Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r) = (\nabla_Y \beta)  (Z_1,\dots,Z_r)$, just two ways to express the same thing. Recall the definition

$(\nabla _Y \beta)(X_1,\dots,X_r) := Y[\beta(X_1,\dots,X_r)] - \beta(\nabla_Y X_1,\dots, X_r) - \dots - \beta(X_1,\dots,\nabla_Y X_r) $

Now I try to compute $(\nabla ^2 \beta)(X,Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r)$

$(\nabla ^2 \beta)(X,Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r) = (\nabla (\nabla \beta))(X,Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r)= (\nabla_X (\nabla \beta))(Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r) = X[ (\nabla \beta)(Y,Z_1,\dots Z_r)] - (\nabla \beta)(\nabla _X Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r) - (\nabla \beta)(Y,\nabla _X  Z_1,\dots,Z_r) - \dots -  (\nabla \beta)(Y,  Z_1,\dots,\nabla _X Z_r) $

Well, according to Chow's Hamilton Ricci Flow it is true that

$(\nabla ^2 \beta)(X,Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r) = X[ (\nabla \beta)(Y,Z_1,\dots Z_r)] - (\nabla \beta)(\nabla _X Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r)$

so I assume that we must have

$ (\nabla \beta)(Y,\nabla _X  Z_1,\dots,Z_r) + \dots +  (\nabla \beta)(Y,  Z_1,\dots,\nabla _X Z_r) = 0 $

and I have no idea how to make the last computation. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your computation is correct. In the book by Chow, Lu and Ni, it is said

$$(\nabla ^2 \beta)(X,Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r) = \nabla_X (\nabla \beta)(Y,Z_1,\dots Z_r) - (\nabla_{\nabla _X Y} \beta)(Z_1,\dots,Z_r)$$ which is different from

$$(\nabla ^2 \beta)(X,Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r) = X[ (\nabla \beta)(Y,Z_1,\dots Z_r)] - (\nabla \beta)(\nabla _X Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r).$$ Note that

$$(\nabla \beta)(\nabla _X Y,Z_1,\dots,Z_r)\ne (\nabla_{\nabla _X Y} \beta)(Z_1,\dots,Z_r).$$

Comment: Thank you for the comment. According to my definitions and Chow's definitions $$(\nabla \beta)(X, Z_1,\dots,Z_r) := (\nabla_X \beta)(Z_1,\dots Z_r).$$ It is on page 7 of Chow's book, so that equality do hold.

Comment: Just look five lines above for a formula for $(\nabla_X\alpha)(Y_1,\cdots,Y_r).$ It's only a question of notation, but can be confusing.

Comment: Maybe pages 13-14 in http://www.math.wisc.edu/~jeffv/courses/865_Fall_2011.pdf are useful.

Comment: I have edited and put in my comment the definition of $(\nabla_X \beta)(X_1,\dots,X_r)$. It is just a matter of commodity to denote $(\nabla \beta)(X,Z_1,\dots Z_r)$ for $(\nabla_X \beta)(X_1,\dots,X_r)$, but it is the same thing. Hope notation is clear now.

Comment: I didn't refer to your comment. I am trying to say that the different you see is a confusion about notation. I insist, read line $10$ from the bottom of page $7$ for the definition of $(\nabla_X\alpha)(Y_1,\cdots,Y_r).$

Comment: I see now, thank you.